# Convert String to Double with specific format

Tags: java, string, double

I´m writing a program in java, I´m trying to convert a String with this format: "1,348,789.925000", into a double: 1348789.925000 I made this:

```
    public class StringToDouble {
    public static Double FormatNumbers(String text)
    {
         text = text.replace(",", "");
         System.out.println("-->: "+text);


          double value = Double.parseDouble(text);  
           return value+1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double myOwnD;
        String text = "1,348,789.925000"; // example String
        myOwnD= FormatNumbers(text);
        System.out.println("--->"+myOwnD);   
    }   
}
```

I got this:

> -->: 1348789.925000
>   --->1348790.925

This is working correctly, but when I try with a bigger number like this: "1,348,789,000.925000" I got this:

> -->: 1348789000.925000
>   --->1.348789001925E9

Could you tell me what is the problem??
Thank you so much

Comment: The problem is with your understanding of numbers as pure numbers don't have a format. It's a meaningless concept for *number* and only applies to visual *representation* of numbers.

Comment: What confuses you on the result? The format is different, yes. But you did not ask for a formatted `String`. You demanded a `Double` and numbers don't have a specific format. Their `toString` representation just changes like you have seen if the number is that big. The reason for that is that it is more readable to humans. The `xE9` notation stands for `x * 10^9` so it's a big number where you move the `dot` `9` places to the right.

Comment: what a shame, Mr Zabuza you are absolutly right!

Comment: I am able to print the desired result using the BigDecimal and printing the result as the string. Here is the link : [Demo](http://rextester.com/KPGQ48027)